# Formula for Picklist with If Conditions

Tags: picklist, formula-field, bestpractice, conditional

I have 1 pick-list called Ward Types. Ward Type
items are,

1. Suite
2. Deluxe
3. Special AC
4. Semi Private
5. General Ward

I want the formula for

```
 if(WardType__c == 'Suite')
 {
    Amount__c = 500;
 }
 if(WardType__c == 'Deluxe')
 {
    Amount__c = 400;
 }
 if(WardType__c == 'Special AC')
 {
    Amount__c = 300;
 }
 if(WardType__c == 'Semi Private')
 {
    Amount__c = 200;
 }
 if(WardType__c == 'General Ward')
 {
    Amount__c = 500;
 }
```

So if Amount__c is a formula field then how can i write formula for this condition.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just set up Amount field as a formula of type number, and then just use a CASE() statement.

```
CASE(
     TEXT(Ward_Type__c),
     "Suite", 500,
     "Deluxe", 400,
     "Special AC", 300,
     "Semi Private", 200,
     "General Ward", 500,
     0
)
```

The last 0 is the else amount.  Basically if there is a value for Ward_Type__c that doesnt match any of the ones you listed, this is the value that will be shown.  You can change that to whatever you want.